# Matlab: Understanding a piece of code

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab code which is for printing a cell array to excel. The size of matrix is 50x13.

The row 1 is the column names.

Column 1 is dates and rest columns are numbers.

The dateformat being defined in the code is:

```
dFormat          =   struct;
dFormat.Style    =   struct( 'NumberFormat', '_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)' );
dFormat.Font     =   struct( 'Size', 8 );
```

Can someone please explain me what the dFormat.Style code means ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line creates an empty [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) (struct with no fields) called `dFormat`. A structure can contain pretty much anything in one of its fields, including another structure. The second line adds a field called `'Style'` to the `dFormat` struct and sets it equal to another struct with a field called `'NumberFormat'`. The `'NumberFormat'` field is set equal to that long string of characters. You now have a structure of structures. The third line is similar to the second.

Note that the first line isn't really necessary unless `dFormat` already exists and it needs to be "zeroed out" as `dFormat.Style` with create it implicitly. However, using the `struct` function can make code more readable in some cases as objects use a similar notation for access methods and properties. In other words, all of your code could be replaced with:

```
dFormat.Style.NumberFormat = '_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)';
dFormat.Font.Size = 8;
```

See [this video](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/04/22/matlab-basics-array-of-structures-vs-structures-of-arrays/) from the MathWorks for more details and this [list of helpful structure functions and examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html).

Comment: Note that it may be considered bad practice to leave out the first initializing line. The answer already implies that a bit but I would like to emphasize it.

Answer (score 0):

@horchler already elaborated on structs, but I imagine you may actually be more interested in the content of this structs Style field.

In case you are solely interested in `_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)`, that does not really look like something MATLAB related to me.

My best guess is that this code is used to later feed some other program, for examle to build an excel file.